# How to get complete metadata of dataset in Palantir Foundry through API call?

Tags: pyspark, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I want to fetch complete metadata of the  given dataset through API call. Can anyone please suggest how to fetch metadata

Comment: Can you clarify what metadata you actually need concretely?

Comment: I assume you already use API, there is a function for it  https://palantirabc.com/foundry-metadata/api/metadata/v2/datasets/{datasetRid}

Answer (score 0):

You actually already manipulate and interact with various forms of metadata inside your Transforms Python builds today, but in a way that is structured to be safe when reading and writing.

While not all forms of metadata are possible to access today, this generally is because of the desire to ensure product stability and good version controls of your builds.

That said, if there's a certain interaction with metadata you'd like to see in the product, I'd recommend reaching out to your support engineers with a feature request so they can understand your request more specifically and discuss with our product teams.